WinCE700 Exception related to the WMS.exe process (version 5.2.8138.19604) with specific details about the error signature
Im getting the following error when I try to install a program on my device:
Error Signature:
Event Type:WinCE700 Exception, P1:WMS.exe, P2:5.2.8138.19604, P3:6256F1F9, P4:mscoree2_0.dll, P5:2.0.7045.0, P6:45d2aab5, P7: 0004a288, P8:WMS.exe, P9:5.2.8138.19604, P10:6256f1f9
Im expecting to find a resolution to my issue if possible.
